# In math mode, how can I display subscripts and superscripts in a different font from other math?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, subscripts

I came across something interesting in Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Erwin Kreyszig. As you can see in this image, subscripts are in a different font from the rest of the math:

[image: Imgur]

How can I achieve this in LaTeX?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico Yet the n _does_ look different in the subscript, it's not only the size. Don't misunderstand me: I don't find this particularly desirable. If I sum terms over an index n I want to use the _same_ n (modulo size) everywhere. Using different font shapes or family for the same index doesn't strike me as particularly useful.

Comment: Yes, it's a prime example of bad typography.

Comment: @campa - You're right. I had initially focused just on the upright vs. italic difference, and I completely failed to notice that Computer Modern (or a close relative) is used in first-level subscripts even though Times Roman is employed for text-style material. I fully agree with you that this setup is anything but desirable.

Comment: @kreyszig-anon Please do not misunderstand us (I think I can speak for Mico and egreg too): your question ("how can I achieve this in LaTeX?") is legitimate. It's just that we think this shouldn't be achieved at all... `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

Only because egreg said it was a bad idea, not because I think you should do this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\sbox0{$$\scriptsize \ttfamily \xdef\tmp{\scriptfont1=\the\font}}\tmp


$x_{abc} = p^2 = abc_{abc}^{10}$

\end{document}
```

you could of course use something other than `\ttfamily` for the font to use.